# The monthly purchase system as like "The Daily"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I would like to make the app for using the monthly purchase system as like "The Daily".

However there is no info about that.

May I have some info about this?

How to add it to my app or how to certify the person who purchase this, and so on.

I'll wait for your thankful reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is an abundance of information about it on the developer site. In fact, there is a giant promo graphic about it. I'm not sure how you missed it but generally the developer center should be your first stop when wondering about a topic like this.

- http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/inapppurchase/subscriptions.html
- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html